# creating a nested <li> structure from simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, jstree, nested-loops, simple-html-dom

Okay, so I'm using the php based simple_html_dom.php found at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to scrape webpages, and what I'd like to do is generate a nested list that reflects the html element structure of the page. Ultimately I plan to initialize jsTree using that list, but I can't get past step one. I know there is a simple straight forward solution to this, but I can't seem to figure one out. I've spent hours searching the web, and finally resorted to posting on here.

Essentially I want to convert this:

```
<body>
    <div id='div0'>
        <span id='span0'> <img id='img1'> </span>
    </div>

    <div id='div1'>
        <span id='span1'>  </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Into this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        div0
        <ul>
            <li>
                span0
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        img1
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        div1
        <ul>
            <li>
                span1
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

An example of what I think is correct would be this, but it generates: `

```
<li><li>`Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in main.php on line 46
```

The code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://www.thefuckingweather.com/");

function create($url)
{
    print "<li>";
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($url as $chi)
    {
        if($chi->tag != "script")
        {
            if (count($chi->children()) > 0)  //#46
            {
                create($chi->children($count));
            }
            else
            {
                print "</li>";
            }
        }
        $count++;
    }   
}

create($html->find("body"));
```

Comment: Please specify what line is #46. if(count->children)?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I swear, maybe this happened because I'm so damn exhausted. The answer was so very simple.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://www.reddit.com/");

foreach ($html->find("body") as $chi)
{
    test($chi);
}

$count = 0;

function test($t)
{
    print "<ul>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($t->children()); $i++)
    {
        print "<li>";
        print $t->children($i)->id . " - " . $t->children($i)->tag . $count++;
        test($t->children($i));
        print "</li>";
    }
    print "</ul>";
}
```